# Cannot create Stubs in java for svc service created in .net

Tags: java, android, wsdl2java

Just some Help me please,

I used WSDL2java jar to generate Stubs.

```
String[] params = new String[] {"-v", "-D", "-oD:\\today", "http://app.dotnetethic.com/UserService.svc?singleWsdl" };
WSDL2Java.main(params);
```

It returns 2 classes Userservice.java , UserserviceLocator.java.

Stub,proxy or port classes are missing.

It will be greatful if some one help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer...

its like changing databinding in service to BasicHttpBinding it works fine..

Thanks